# Why is my .net 6 class library showing up with a unit test icon in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, csproj

I have added a .net 6 class library project to a solution using Visual Studio 2022 and it is showing up with a test icon

[image]

While this doesnt affect the functionality of the library it is slightly annoying.

**Thing I have checked**

- Csproj file SDK type which is `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`
- No .Net.Test nuget packages
- Set OutputType to library
- Nothing obvious in the Solution file

[image]

**Csproj file looks like the following:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Anything special in a `Directory.Build.props` file?

Comment: where would I find that file? I cant seem to find one in the project folder

Comment: That file can be anywhere from your project folder to the root of the drive. Typically, it's in the solution folder (so one or two directory levels up from the project). It's contents are included in every project within the solution.